# Copy Range if cell is <= value

Tags: vba, excel

I need to copy a range to a new sheet based off data in 1 cell
I have 100 rows of data.  Data starts in row 11.

If cell E >= 13 copy range B11:E11 to sheet 2
If cell E <= 12 copy range B11:E11 to sheet 3

```
Sheets1.Select
For n = 11 To 129
If Cells(n, 5) >= 13 Then
Range("B" & n, "E" & n).Copy sheets2.Range("B11")
Else
Range("B" & n, "E" & n).Copy sheet3.Range("B11")
End If
Next n
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

**EDIT:**
Thank you for your help everyone.  Here is what I have now.

```
Sub ConditionalCopy()

  Dim ws1, ws2, ws3, ws4, ws5, ws6, ws7, ws As Worksheet
  Dim row1, row2, row3, row4, row5, row6, row7, row As Integer

  Set ws1 = Worksheets("1ST BROWN")
  Set ws2 = Worksheets("1ST BROWN NOTES")
  Set ws3 = Worksheets("KIDS BROWN NOTES")
  Set ws4 = Worksheets("2ND BROWN")
  Set ws5 = Worksheets("2ND BROWN NOTES")
  Set ws6 = Worksheets("3RD BROWN")
  Set ws7 = Worksheets("3RD BROWN NOTES")

  row2 = 10
  row3 = 10

  For row1 = 11 To 129
    If ws1.Cells(row1, 5).Value >= 13 Then
      Set ws = ws2
      row2 = row2 + 1
      row = row2
    Else
      Set ws = ws3
      row3 = row3 + 1
      row = row3
    End If

    ws.Range("B" & row & ":E" & row).Value = _
      ws1.Range("B" & row1 & ":E" & row1).Value

  Next row1

  row5 = 10

  For row4 = 11 To 129
    If ws4.Cells(row4, 5).Value >= 13 Then
      Set ws = ws5
      row5 = row5 + 1
      row = row5
    Else
      Set ws = ws3
      row3 = row3 + 1
      row = row3
    End If

    ws.Range("B" & row & ":E" & row).Value = _
      ws4.Range("B" & row4 & ":E" & row4).Value

  Next row4

  row7 = 10

  For row6 = 11 To 129
    If ws6.Cells(row6, 5).Value >= 13 Then
      Set ws = ws7
      row7 = row7 + 1
      row = row7
    Else
      Set ws = ws3
      row3 = row3 + 1
      row = row3
    End If

    ws.Range("B" & row & ":E" & row).Value = _
      ws6.Range("B" & row6 & ":E" & row6).Value

  Next row6


End Sub
```

Comment: Change the range parameters to the following form: `Range("B" & n & ":E" & n)`

Comment: In addition to what Miqi180 said, the way it is currently set up will **always** write to cells B11:E11 of `sheets2` or `sheet3` (should that `sheet2` and/or `sheets3`?) rather than to a new row.  Is that what you want, or do you want to write to the next empty row on each of those sheets?

Comment: Thank you Miqi and Yow.  I want it to go to the next row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have your row hard-coded in the copy.  I wasn't sure if you want the data sequential (in other words, sheet 1 has 100 rows, so sheets 2 + 3 should total 100 with no gaps) or if you wanted the data on the same row it was in sheet 1.  This example assumes no gaps.

```
Sub ConditionalCopy()

  Dim ws1, ws2, ws3, ws As Worksheet
  Dim row1, row2, row3, row As Integer

  Set ws1 = Sheets(1)
  Set ws2 = Sheets(2)
  Set ws3 = Sheets(3)

  row2 = 10
  row3 = 10

  For row1 = 11 To 129
    If ws1.Cells(row1, 5).Value >= 13 Then
      Set ws = ws2
      row2 = row2 + 1
      row = row2
    Else
      Set ws = ws3
      row3 = row3 + 1
      row = row3
    End If

    ws.Range("B" & row & ":E" & row).Value = _
      ws1.Range("B" & row1 & ":E" & row1).Value

  Next row1

End Sub
```

If possible, I really discourage select / copy / paste methodology.  VBA has better ways of moving data.  In the example above, we took the values from an entire range and moved them to another range.

See if this is close to what you had in mind.

-- EDIT --

It turns out, the data is there!  You just need to scroll down to see it.

The problem is it is still moving the rows of data, even when there is no "real" data to move.  You are iterating rows 11 to 129 and copying, even if blank.

I recommend you short circut each `for` loop based on the student's name.  If it's blank, quit the loop.  This should allow the names on your "Kids" sheet to be sequential.

Here are some snippets that would do it:

For "First Brown:"

```
For row1 = 11 To 129

  If ws1.Cells(row1, 4).Value = "" Then
    Exit For
  End If
```

"Second Brown:"

```
For row4 = 11 To 129

  If ws4.Cells(row4, 4).Value = "" Then
    Exit For
  End If
```

"Third Brown:"

```
For row6 = 11 To 129

  If ws4.Cells(row6, 4).Value = "" Then
    Exit For
  End If
```

-- EDIT 10/18/2016 --

Here is a streamlined version of the code that does it for all three sheets, using the same code.  I tested it, and it also does not appear to skip lines.

```
Sub ConditionalCopy()

  Dim source, destination, kids, ws As Worksheet
  Dim iteration, sRow, dRow, kRow, row As Integer

  Set kids = Worksheets("KIDS BROWN NOTES")
  kRow = 10

  For iteration = 1 To 3
    sRow = 10
    dRow = 10

    If iteration = 1 Then
      Set source = Worksheets("1ST BROWN")
      Set destination = Worksheets("1ST BROWN NOTES")
    ElseIf iteration = 2 Then
      Set source = Worksheets("2ND BROWN")
      Set destination = Worksheets("2ND BROWN NOTES")
    Else
      Set source = Worksheets("3RD BROWN")
      Set destination = Worksheets("3RD BROWN NOTES")
    End If

    For sRow = 11 To 129
      If source.Cells(sRow, 4).Value = "" Then
        Exit For
      End If

      If source.Cells(sRow, 5).Value >= 13 Then
        Set ws = destination
        dRow = dRow + 1
        row = dRow
      Else
        Set ws = kids
        kRow = kRow + 1
        row = kRow
      End If

      ws.Range("B" & row & ":E" & row).Value = _
          source.Range("B" & sRow & ":E" & sRow).Value
    Next sRow
  Next iteration

End Sub
```

-- EDIT 2 10/18/2016 --

Regarding `Run_Before_Test` I think you want a slightly different approach.  I recommend you use one of my favorite structures, the Dictionary structure.  You need to add this in VBA from Tools->References and put a check next to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime."  Once you do that, you can access the Dictionary and take advantage of intellisense with it as well.

See if this code makes sense.  You may need minor tweaks, but I think it's easy enough to read (and modify):

```
Sub RunBeforeTest()
  Dim BeltSheet As New Dictionary
  Dim RowNumbers As New Dictionary
  Dim master As ListObject
  Dim lr As ListRow
  Dim source, dest As Worksheet
  Dim row As Integer

  BeltSheet.Add "Jr. Black", Sheets("BLACK")
  BeltSheet.Add "1st Black", Sheets("BLACK")
  BeltSheet.Add "2nd Black", Sheets("BLACK")
  BeltSheet.Add "3rd Black", Sheets("BLACK")
  BeltSheet.Add "4th Black", Sheets("BLACK")
  BeltSheet.Add "5th Black", Sheets("BLACK")
  BeltSheet.Add "6th Black", Sheets("BLACK")
  BeltSheet.Add "1st Brown", Sheets("1ST BROWN")
  BeltSheet.Add "2nd Brown", Sheets("2ND BROWN")
  BeltSheet.Add "3rd Brown", Sheets("3RD BROWN")
  RowNumbers.Add Sheets("BLACK"), 11
  RowNumbers.Add Sheets("1ST BROWN"), 11
  RowNumbers.Add Sheets("2ND BROWN"), 11
  RowNumbers.Add Sheets("3RD BROWN"), 11

  Set master = Sheets("MASTER").ListObjects("Table2")
  For Each lr In master.ListRows
    If lr.Range(1, 1).Value = "" Then
      Exit For
    End If

    Set ws = BeltSheet(lr.Range(1, 1).Value)
    row = RowNumbers(ws)

    ws.Range("B" & row & ":E" & row).Value = lr.Range.Value

    RowNumbers(ws) = row + 1
  Next lr
End Sub
```

Also, I did not know until I saw that code that these sheets are actually using Tables!  That makes it so much easier.  The original solution can also be reengineered to take advantage of the table structures.

Comment: Thank you Hambone.  This worked great.  I tried to add code to make it work on the other sheets but when it copies to ws7 it skips rows and doesn't copy the under 12 to ws3.  Can you look at what I did?

Comment: I fixed the skipping row problem but I'm not getting anything that is <13 to copy to ws3 from ws4 or ws6

Comment: Any chance you can upload the document to G-Drive / Dropbox or whatever?  It's probably something really minor.  The little issues are the hardest to find

Comment: You're going to laugh at the issue...  please see edit.

Comment: Thanks Hambone.  That worked.  I got 2 blank rows when I did it though?

Comment: What would be the easiest way to adapt the other macro in that file so it works like this?  I tried to copy that style but it wouldn't allow me to use the or statement in it.

Comment: Regarding the blank rows...  I think the `row3 = row3 + 1` was invoked one too many times in each loop.  You can get really cute to fix this, or you can just do `row3 = row3 - 1` outside of each loop, and that should fix the blank lines.  I've slept since I last looked at the workbook.  Let me see it again to see which Macro you refer to.

Comment: Okay, I give up.  Which macro?

Comment: It's called Run_before_test.    'For Each c In Source.Range("b11:b110")'

Comment: `row3 = row3 - 1` didn't work.  It would up not moving the lines.

Comment: I made an edit with an improved version of the logic -- it's shorter, and if you make changes you won't have to make them three times now.  Also, it doesn't appear to have the skipped lines.  I'll take a look at `Run_before_test` and let you know if I find anything

Comment: Check out the revised version of `RunBeforeTest()`

Answer (score -1):

should be Cells(n,5).Value

```
Sheets1.Select
For n = 11 To 129
If Cells(n, 5).Value >= 13 Then
Range("B" & n, "E" & n).Copy sheets2.Range("B11")
Else
Range("B" & n, "E" & n).Copy sheet3.Range("B11")
End If
Next n
```

Comment: Due to the "default" properties of objects, `Cells(n, 5)` is equivalent to `Cells(n, 5).Value` in this situation.

Comment: default properties?? i dont understand this part, how could you tell its default properties?

Comment: The Excel Range class has, as its default property, `Value`.  This means if you use the range indexer you don't **have** to specify the `Value` to return the value.  I actually don't like it and prefer to explicitly call `Value` (or `Value2` or `Text` depending on the need), as you have done.  That said, it does work that way and you will find it's widely accepted and used as a shortcut, so it's important to understand.  I think YowE3K's point is that this, alone, would not be the cause of the OP's issue, as there is no functional difference in his code and yours

Comment: Like @Hambone I prefer to explicitly code the property even when I know that the default property in the situation is the one I am using.  There's always a (very small) chance that Microsoft may decide to change in a future version of VBA what the default property is - e.g. they may decide that the `Range` object's default property is `.Address` when casting to a String, but the `.Value` property when casting to an Integer.  And I find it easier to understand what the code is doing if the property is explicitly stated.